# If $e^f$ is holomorphic, then so is $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be defined on some open set. Is it true that if $e^f$ is holomorphic, then so is $f$?

I believe this is true. But I do not know how to prove it. Please help.

Comment: This is false unless you requite more of $f.$ For example consider the function $f=0$ everywhere except $0, f(0) = 2\pi i.$

Comment: Yes it is false but it is not crazy false. $f$ must be holomorphic on big open pieces of the plan.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and $e^f$ is holomorphic then $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: @ user1952009, I would really like to know how to prove that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no conditions on f, then this is false. For example, take $f(z)$ to be some branch of the logarithm on an open annulus, with the values along the negative real axis being continuous from those on the upper half plane but not from the lower half plane.

f is not continuous, but $e^{f(z)}=z$ is holomorphic.

Comment: You could make it much simpler : $f(z)=0$ for $Re(z) \ge 0, f(z) = 2i\pi$ for $Re(z) < 0$. Then $e^{f(z)} = 1$.

Comment: Or just look at my example.