# Establishing Analyticity of Function f

Tags: complex-analysis

G is a domain in the complex plane.

Consider the function $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, which is both complex and continuous within G.

Additionally, we have the relation $e^{f(z)} = z$.

**I know that inorder to show that f is analytic I need to show the following:**

**1.** Show that G is an open set (This is inherently true as G is a domain).

**2.** Confirm that f is differentiable within G.

It's worth noting that the function $e^x$ exhibits both continuity and differentiability within G. Given that f(z) is continuous across G, we can deduce the continuity of $e^{f(z)}$ within G.

I'm seeking your assistance in establishing a connection between these points to demonstrate that f is analytic.

Comment: More general result: If $g$ is analytic, $f$ is continuous, $g\circ f$ is analytic and $g'$ has no zeros then $f$ is analytic.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you, But what do you mean by g' has no zeros?

Comment: In your case $g(z)=e^{z}$ So $g'(z)=e^{z} \neq 0$ for any $z$. There are  lots of other functions $g$ with this property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that $e^{f(z)} = z$ implies that $f$ is injective in $G$.

For $z, z_0$ in $G$ with $z \ne z_0$ is $f(z) \ne f(z_0)$ and
$$
 \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} = \left(\frac{e^{f(z)}-e^{f(z_0)}}{f(z)-f(z_0)}\right)^{-1} \, .
$$

If $(z_n)$ is a sequence in $G \setminus \{ z_0 \}$ converging to $z_0$ then  $w:= f(z_n)$ converges to $w_0 := f(z_0)$ because $f$ is assumed to be continuous, and

$$
 \frac{f(z_n)-f(z_0)}{z_n-z_0} = \left(\frac{e^{w_n}-e^{w_0}}{w_n - w_0}\right)^{-1} \to \frac{1}{e^{w_0}}
$$
since the exponential function is complex differentiable at $w_0$ with $\exp' = \exp$. It follows that the limit
$$
 \lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}
$$
exists (and is equal to $1/e^{f(z_0)}$).

*Remark:* Without the assumption that $f$ is continuous the conclusion may not hold, see for example [If $e^f$ is holomorphic, then so is $f$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2259152/42969).

Comment: Thanks you for you answer. To explain the transition from the expression in the parentheses it enough to say that? $e^{f(x)}$ is continuous (because e^x and f are continuous) at G. And Because $e^{f(x)}$ is continuous the limit at point $x_{0}$ exists and is $e^{f(x_{0}}$. The thing that confuses me is the fact that I cant say at this stage that f is differentiable and so I can't say about that $e^{f(x)}$ is differentiable.

Comment: @MyLight: It is only used at that point that $f(z) \to f(z_0)$ for $z \to z_0$, and that the exponential function is differentiable at $f(z_0)$.

Comment: @MyLight: Is it clearer now?